# Forgotten where I left an automatic shutdown script on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, applescript, parallels

I let me Parallels Desktop running Windows XP to start automatically during mac log-in. And to start Windows upon launch to let my dad use his WinXP by just pressing the power button, bypassing the Mac login window and desktop completely. When he shuts down Windows, Parallels closes.

I seem to remember I have a trigger to shut down mac as soon as Parallels closes. But I don't remember where... I have an AppleScript that tells Finder to shut down. I understand that. But now the problem is Mac shuts down AS SOON AS it boots up every time! I can't figure out what's triggering the shutdown... And I've run out of places to look.

It seems like a normal shut down rather than a fatal error. Seems like someone has chosen the 'Shut Down' command as soon as Mac starts up. So could mac gurus suggest places I should look -- what might have triggered this -- I'm pretty sure it's Parallels-related. Maybe there is something in the Package Contents linked to the shutdown script??

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's an operating system question, and therefore belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). Voting to close and migrate it there. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You added the Applescript (that shut down the mac) to login items